# Multiple independent correlations (Pearson) with R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a table where columns represent climatic variables, and rows representing data points for each of the variable.  I want to set up simple Pearson correlation between for every pairwise combination.  I can do this manually, but it would be nice to have a function that can do all of these automatically and print results to a new R object.

```
County  temp  gdd  ai  precip
Jackson 
Robinson
Paris
Rose
Wine
```

Answer (score 4):

`cor` can actually handle matrices and return a matrix. So if your `data.frame` is `DF`, you can run:

```
DF <- data.frame(temp = rnorm(10), gdd=rnorm(10), ai=rnorm(10), precip=rnorm(10))
cor(as.matrix(DF))

             temp        gdd         ai     precip
temp    1.0000000 -0.5946187 -0.4635090  0.8016484
gdd    -0.5946187  1.0000000  0.2184197 -0.2878479
ai     -0.4635090  0.2184197  1.0000000 -0.2788024
precip  0.8016484 -0.2878479 -0.2788024  1.0000000
```

If your `data.frame` contains all `numeric` columns, you can just do `cor(DF)`. If there's `character` or `factor` columns, you'll want to run `cor` on a selection of only numeric columns from `DF`. (Now that I think of it, the "`asmatrix(DF)`" part is kind of unnecessary).

Comment: O: Thank you.  Thats very helpful. I take it these are correlation coefficients.  How can I obtain P values?

Comment: I'd use the website [Rseek](http://www.rseek.org/) to search for these types of questions before posing as questions here.  `library(ltm); rcor.test(mtcars)` is oe approach.